# C# - How to find out which dynamic button was clicked?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button, dynamic

I am writing a program where I dynamically add buttons, I do that by storing them in a Dictionary to get a certain value from them later on (the color of the background).

I need to set a Click event on every one of them, but every Click event has to be a little different, as by clicking the button, a ColorDialog pops up and changes the background of the button.

Is there a way to know which button I clicked? In the following code, the button1 click event adds the other buttons and sets the EventHandler for each of them, what should be the code for the EventHandler? Thank you so much in advance guys.

```
int i = 0;
Dictionary<int, Button> buttonDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Button>();
Dictionary<int, ColorDialog> colorsDictionary = new Dictionary<int ColorDialog>();


public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i++;
    buttonDictionary.Add(i, new Button());
    buttonDictionary[i].Click += new EventHandler(Click);
    this.Controls.Add(buttonDictionary[i]);
}

public void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Somehow get the int key of the button that was clicked???? (in this case: int j)

    int j;

    if (!colorsDictionary.ContainsKey(j))
    {
        colorsDictionary.Add(j, new ColorDialog());
    }

    if (colorsDictionary[j].ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        buttonDictionary[j].BackColor = colorsDictionary[j].Color;
    }
}
```

The code is made just for **adding** the buttons, I will be glad for any kind of help, thank you guys!

Comment: Use `sender`, cast it to `Button` and then check for equality with the items in the dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a direct answer to your question is:  cast the `sender` to a `Button`

```
Button pressedButton = (Button) sender;
```

and then check to which button of the dictionary it matches:

```
foreach (var entry in buttonDictionary)
{
    if (entry.Value == pressedButton)
    {
        j = entry.Key;
        break;
    }
}
```

However, that's overly complex for what you want to achieve. It would be much easier if you had a direct relationship between the button and the color picker:

```
Dictionary<Button, ColorDialog> buttonDictionary = new Dictionary<Button, ColorDialog>();
```

Then fill it like this:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i++;
    var button = new Button();
    this.Controls.Add(button);
    button.Click += new EventHandler(Click);

    buttonDictionary.Add(button, null);
}
```

And later access it with

```
public void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button pressedButton = (Button) sender;
    ColorDialog dialog = buttonDictionary[pressedButton];

    if (dialog == null)
    {
        dialog = new ColorDialog();
        buttonDictionary[pressedButton] = dialog;
    }

    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        pressedButton.BackColor = dialog.Color;
    }
}
```

Even more, the question is why you would need so many ColorDialgos, since it should be possible with one dialog only. You can get rid of `i`, `j`, all dictionaries and most handling as well. IMHO, the following should be sufficient:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = new Button();
    Controls.Add(button);
    button.Click += Click;
}

public void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button pressedButton = (Button) sender;
    ColorDialog dialog = new ColorDialog {Color = pressedButton.BackColor};
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        pressedButton.BackColor = dialog.Color;
    }
}
```

Bonus info:

I don't exactly know what you want to achieve. But your buttons will all be in the same place, overlapping each other. To avoid this, drag a flow layout panel onto the form and then add the buttons to the flow layout:

```
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button);
```

This will ensure that your buttons are nicely arranged.

[image: Buttons arranged]

Comment: Thank you so much Thomas! You have no idea how much I appreciate the fact that you took your time to explain all this to me. You are a good guy, thank you so much once again! I wish all the best to you.

Comment: @spoky: I'm glad I could help and you learned something. Have fun while programming.

Comment: @spoky: If you have tested the answer and it works, then click the checkmark to indicate that the problem was solved.

Comment: @spoky: I've added some info to arrange buttons automatically.

Comment: I forgot to check it, thank you for reminding me! I was aware of the buttons overlapping, I wanted to solve that by setting a different location to each of them that would be increasing with a click, but didnt know you can do this! Thank you so much once again, I really appreciate it